# Finding the longest sequence of number in array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to find the longest sequence of a given number in an array. For example,

Given:

```
int number = 5;
int[] array = new int[]{5,5,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,1,2};
```

This should print 3 since 5,5,5 is the longest sequence of 5s. But if the number was 1, it would print 4.

I came up with:

```
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == number) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > max) {
        max = count;
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

But this doesn't work if `int number = 0` and the array is `{10,3,0,0,2,6,7,2,0,2,-1,-3,0,0,0,0,0,2,-3,-4,-5,0,0,0,0}`

It prints 6 instead of 5.

What am I missing?

Comment: Move `count = 0;` outside of the `if` block. You need to reset that whenever a `5` is not found, not just when the max sequence is found.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises if the array first includes a sequence of the wanted number of length `x`, then a sequence of the wanted number of length `y < x` and then the longest sequence of wanted number of length `z`. The relevant part is the sequence of length `y < x`.

Since `y < x`, the statement `if (count > max)` is `false`. Hence, `count = 0;` is not executed and `count` is still on `y`.

Then, when the code starts increasing the `count` again for the longest sequence, it keeps increasing `count`, which is `y`, but should be `0`. Therefore, the final `count` is `y + z`, where it should only be `z`.

For the array provided, we can see that `x = 2`, `y = 1` and `z = 5`:

```
{10,3,0,0,2,6,7,2,0,2,-1,-3,0,0,0,0,0,2,-3,-4,-5,0,0,0,0} 
     | x |       |y|       |    z    |
```

The fix is to move `count` out of the `if`, into the `else`:

```
        ...
        } else {
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        ...
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/mfRvxy)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to check the max every time around the loop and reset the count to zero whenever the number doesn't match. I think you can simplify your logic somewhat by checking for a new maximum right after incrementing the count, and using an enhanced for loop.

```
int count = 0;
int max = 0;
for (int x : array) {
    if (x == number) {
        count++;
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;  // a new maximum has been achieved 
        }
    } else {
        count = 0;  // the number does not match
    }
}
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the length of the sequence inside an array, the main loop should be split in two parts:

- skip all the numbers which are NOT equal to `number`
- count the length of sequence until the first non-number element is detected or end of array occurs whichever comes first

```java
static int lengthOfLongest(int number, int ... array) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        while (i < array.length && array[i] != number) i++; // skip
        for (int j = i; j < array.length && array[j] == number; j++, i++) {
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("lost at " + i + "; count = " + count);
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);    
    return max;
}
```

Test:

```java
lengthOfLongest(0,
    10,3,0,0,2,6,7,2,0,2,-1,-3,0,0,0,0,0,2,-3,-4,-5,0,0,0,0
);
```

Output (with debug logs)

```
found at 2
lost at 4; count = 2
found at 8
lost at 9; count = 1
found at 12
lost at 17; count = 5
found at 21
lost at 25; count = 4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by sorting your array, then use a `HashMap` to count the sequence:

```
int[] array = new int[]{5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2};
var length = array.length;


// sort the array
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        var temp = array[i];
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    length--;
} while (length != 0);

// print the array after sorting
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

//calculate the sequence of each element and store it in a HashMap
HashMap<Integer,Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

for (int j : array) {
    var count = 0;
    for (int k : array) {
        if (k == j) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    result.put(j, count);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Finally you use a simple stream operation to get the max sequence:

```
//retrieve the max sequence
final Optional<Integer> max = result.values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
max.ifPresent(integer -> System.out.println("max number is " + integer));
```

Console:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
{1=5, 2=1, 5=5}
max number is 5
```

> Java version used : 16.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int longestSequence(int[] array) {
    int length = array.length;
    if (length == 0)
        return 0;
    int max = 1, prev = array[0], count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < length; prev = array[i], ++i)
        if (array[i] != prev)
            count = 1;
        else if (++count > max)
            max = count;
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 10, 3, 0, 0, 2, 6, 7, 2, 0, 2, -1, -3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, -3, -4, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    System.out.println(longestSequence(array));
}
```

output:

```
5
```